# Swift unable to dequeue a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created an extension for table view to easy register cells:

```
extension UITableView {

    func mapTableViewWithCellsDictionary(dictionary : [String : String]) -> Void {

        for (key, _) in dictionary {
            self.register(NSClassFromString(dictionary[key]!), forCellReuseIdentifier: key)
        }

    }
}
```

In my view controller i did :

```
  let dct = ["VacanciesItem":"VacanciesCell"]
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.mapTableViewWithCellsDictionary(dictionary: dct)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Then:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell : ModelBinding  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VacanciesItem", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ModelBinding
    cell.bindWithModel(model: self.viewModel.arrValues[indexPath.row])

    return cell as! UITableViewCell
}
```

However, app cant see that cell, it throw an error:

```
'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier VacanciesItem - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

But i already did register it.

Comment: Have you given cell identifier in Attribute inspecter?

Comment: you are registering different cell class name, and you dequeing some other class name, i am suspecting here

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```
for (key, _) in dictionary {
        self.register(NSClassFromString(dictionary[key]!), forCellReuseIdentifier: key)
    }
```

You're using `VacanciesItem` as both class and reuse identifier. I assume you meant

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
        self.register(NSClassFromString(dictionary[value]!), forCellReuseIdentifier: key)
    }
```

so that you'll register `VacanciesCell` class with `VacanciesItem` identifier

Comment: What seems to be the issue? I made an assumption that `VacanciesItem` is the reuse identifier, and `VacanciesCell` is the cell class. Was I mistaken? Which one is which?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the below line of code, what does the `key and value pairs` specify?

```
  let dct = ["VacanciesItem":"VacanciesCell"]
```

To register a `xib`, you need to specify the `UINib` object if you are making the cell using `xib`.

Considering, in `dct`,  `key("VacanciesItem")` is the `xib name` and `value("VacanciesCell")` is the `cell identifier`,

```
   func mapTableViewWithCellsDictionary(dictionary : [String : String]) -> Void
   {
            for (nibName, identifier) in dictionary
            {
                self.register(UINib(nibName: nibName), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            }
   }
```

If you are creating UITableViewCell using code, then to register it use:

```
    let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String;
    self.tableView.register(NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(nibName)") as? UITableViewCell.Type, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
```

In swift, you also need to add `namespace(project name)` with `file name` to get it identified.

Comment: i dont use storyboards or xib, i create cells programmatically.

Comment: @PGDev "To register a xib, you need to specify the UINib object and not the class name." - [you can register a cell with either xib or a class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register)

Comment: @mag_zbc I thought he is making the cells using xib. Thanks anyways. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your extension as below

```
extension UITableView {

    func mapTableViewWithCellsDictionary(dictionary : [String : String]) -> Void {

        for (key, _) in dictionary {
            self.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing:dictionary[key]!), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: key)
        }

    }
}
```